# How to get Opera work correctly with Privoxy?

Tags: proxy, opera, privoxy

I use Privoxy and recently switched back to Opera as browser. Anything is fine, but one thing is annoying: Everytime I start the computer I have to restart privoxy (`sudo /etc/init.d/privoxy restart`) or Opera shows an error, that it cannot reach the proxy. What is wrong here?

Comment: sounds like a problem with the browser not privoxy...that's just me...maybe some logs would be helpful.  is privoxy started before the restart?  ps -A | grep privoxy...i prefer proxychains to privoxy and manually setting the proxy in the browser.

Comment: Privoxy is started. It works fine with Firefox. But a restart solves that problem. But I don't want make a restart anytime I start my system.

Comment: Did you check the privoxy log for any errors or warnings?

Comment: And maybe if you can find Opera logs about what it tries to do that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not an issue with Opera. It's a problem with Privoxy. My Privoxy logfile in `/var/log/privoxy/logfile` mumbles about "Fatal error: can't bind to 192.168.2.3:8118: Cannot assign requested address".

It's caused by this bug: [privoxy not start at boot - karmic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/privoxy/+bug/427625).

A workaround is available, which delays the startup of Privoxy. Quoted from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/privoxy/+bug/427625/comments/17:

> Further workaround suggestions: rename /etc/rc2.d/S?0privoxy to /etc/rc2.d/S99privoxy. If even that doesn't work, then edit /etc/init.d/privoxy and replace the do_start function with the following:
>
> ```
> ((begins))
> do_start()
> {
>  # Return
>  # 0 if daemon has been started
>  # 1 if daemon was already running
>  # 2 if daemon could not be started
>  start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
>   || return 1
>  start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
>   $DAEMON_ARGS \
>   && return 0
>  # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
>  # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
>  # on this one. As a last resort, sleep for some time.
>         sleep 1
>  start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
>   $DAEMON_ARGS \
>   || return 2
> }
> ((ends))
> ```