# Why does Privoxy needs a restart at boot?

Tags: 10.04, proxy, privoxy

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 installed and I installed Privoxy:

```
apt-get install -y privoxy
```

Okay, it works great with my rules, fine.

When I boot up my desktop PC I can see that Privoxy is started, it runs, great.
But when I want to view webpages through it it doesn't work (error loading page).

But if i restart the privoxy with

```
service privoxy restart
```

then it works!

What could the problem be? Why do I have to restart Privoxy after every boot?

Comment: try adding some log files, maybe output of dmesg... sometimes it is  easier with log files than just guessing

Comment: or I think the problem is that I didn't set privoxy to start "normally" at boot? :\ how to set it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It likely that Privoxy did not start successfully because it started before the Network interface was initialised - there is a similar bug report with [Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=711587).

### Suggestion 1

Starting privoxy was also discussed on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9188263).

Have a look at the file `/var/log/privoxy`

If there is an error in the file that looks like "Fatal error: can't bind to localhost:8118: The hostname is not resolvable" then change the listen-address in the privoxy configuration file `/etc/privoxy/config`.

i.e. change "listen-address  localhost:8118" to be "listen-address  127.0.0.1:8118"

### Suggestion 2

The author of the Fedora bug report suggested adding the following line of text to `/etc/rc.local` i.e. add it before "exit 0" not after it.

`/bin/sleep 20 && /etc/init.d/privoxy start`

Answer (score 0):

You likely see "Fatal error: can't bind to 192.168.2.3:8118: Cannot assign requested address" in your `/var/log/privoxy/logfile` file which means that the network interface has not become ready yet.

In that case, you're affected by [Launchpad bug #427625](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/privoxy/+bug/427625) which is [fixed in 3.0.16-1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/privoxy/+bug/427625/comments/48), but Lucid is still shipped with 3.0.15-3. As a workaround, you can try the fix as described in [How to get Opera work correctly with Privoxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13976/how-to-get-opera-work-correctly-with-privoxy/16349#16349).